# Django group by one column but display multiple

Tags: python, mysql, django, group-by

I have 40 results of posts in Django.

POST: id, title, website_id

WEBSITE: id, name

And these posts belong to 7 websites.

I would like to group by website_id so only 1 post will be displayed per a website.

I've tried this:

```
post_list.values('website_id').annotate(Count('website_id'))
```

or

```
post_list.values('id', 'title').values('website_id').annotate(Count('website_id'))
```

It will display 7 results, but only 2 columns: "website_id" and "website_id__count"

I would like to display also other columns:

post.id, post.title, post.website_id.

I've tried different configurations, such as:

```
post_list.values('id', 'title', 'website_id').annotate(Count('website_id'))
```

Now, it displays all columns, but 40 results instead of 7, because it groups by post.id instead of post.website_id.

Do you know how to display all columns but only 7 results, instead of 40? Thanks.

Comment: The order matters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses

Comment: To display all the columns, you need to choose some sort of aggregation for the columns you are not grouping by. Could be `MAX`, `MIN`, `GROUP_CONCAT` or `COUNT` etc. since it will need to show only one value for each row.

Comment: Thanks. It works.

post_list.values('website_id').annotate(id=Max('id'), title=Max('title'))

Answer (score 0):

Define an Aggregate class

```
from django.db.models import Aggregate
class RawColumn(Aggregate):
    function = ''
    template = '%(function)s%(expressions)s'

    def __init__(self, expressions, **extra):
        super(RawColumn, self).__init__(expressions, **extra)

post_list.values('website_id').annotate(Count('website_id'),RawColumn('id'),RawColumn('title'))
```